# split based on multiple numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Can you help me figure out how to split based on multiple/group of number as delimiter?

I have content in a file in below format:

```
data_file_10572_2018-02-15-12-57-29.file
header_file_13238_2018-02-15-12-57-48.file
sig_file1_17678_2018-02-15-12-57-14.file
```

Expected output:

```
data_file
header_file
sig_file1
```

I'm new to python and I'm not sure how to cut based on group of number. Thanks for the reply!!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you. Method finds the element that can be casted to integer and return a string up to this value.

```
data = ['data_file_10572_2018-02-15-12-57-29.file', 'header_file_13238_2018-02-15-12-57-48.file', 'sig_file1_17678_2018-02-15-12-57-14.file']

def split_before_int(elem):
    filename = elem.split('_')
    for part in filename:
        if not isinstance(part, (int)):
                return '_'.join(filename[:filename.index(part)-2])

for elem in data:
    print(split_before_int(elem))
```

Output:

```
data_file
header_file
sig_file1
```

Comment: For the filenames `archive_2725_2018-02-22-04-15-58.file` and `archive_fl_data_725_2018-02-22-04-15-58.file` it return `archive` and `archive_fl_data`.

Answer (score 0):

First `index` to get the second location of the `_` symbol, then python list partial indexing (i.e. `list[0:5]`) to get a substring up to the location of the second `_`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But the number of character can differ, sometimes there are archive_2725_2018-02-22-04-15-58.file archive_fl_data_725_2018-02-22-04-15-58.file

Answer (score 0):

```
files = ['data_file_10572_2018-02-15-12-57-29.file', 'header_file_13238_2018-02-15-12-57-48.file','sig_file1_17678_2018-02-15-12-57-14.file']
cleaned_files = list(map(lambda file: '_'.join(file.split('_')[0:2]), files))
```

This results in:

```
['data_file', 'header_file', 'sig_file1']
```

Comment: Hi, there is no pattern to the name. Sometimes the file names are like - archive_2725_2018-02-22-04-15-58.file archive_fl_data_725_2018-02-22-04-15-58.file

Comment: You can either replace the underscore in split('_') with a string of numbers, or use a regular expression like in Rakesh's answer. But it's hard to us to provide a solution that anticipates fringe cases solely based on the details you provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split by "_" with regex and then join the elements excluding the last

**Ex:**

```
import re
a = "data_file_10572_2018-02-15-12-57-29.file"
print "_".join(re.match("(.*?)_\d",a).group().split("_")[:-1])
```

**output:**

```
data_file
```

Comment: Hi, there is no pattern to the name. Sometimes the file names are like - archive_2725_2018-02-22-04-15-58.file archive_fl_data_725_2018-02-22-04-15-58.file

Comment: Updated solution

Answer (score 0):

This code will work if all you filenames follow the pattern you described.

```
filename = 'data_file_10572_2018-02-15-12-57-29.file'
parts = filename.split('_')
new_filename = '_'.join(parts[:2])
```

If alphabetical part fo file name has variable number of underscores it's better to use Regex.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('_[0-9_-]{3,}.file$')
re.sub(pattern, '', filename)
```

Output:

```
data_file
```

Essentially, first, it creates a pattern that starts with _, followed by 3 or more numbers, _ or - and ends with .file.
Then you replace the largest substring of you string that follows this pattern with an empty string.

Comment: Hi, there is no pattern. Sometimes the file names are like - archive_2725_2018-02-22-04-15-58.file archive_fl_data_725_2018-02-22-04-15-58.file